# Print the same child nodes from an object but two levels deep

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a piece of JavaScript that can read through specific parts of a linked object and place them iteratively into another piece of code which then places the code into HTML and into the front-end.

I've managed to get the fetch part working whereby it pulls in the JSON and can be read in the console, when summoned. Once the code runs, I'm able to refer to the data and bring out the whole dataset with something like:

```
console.log(AllOffers);
```

and I can drill down into something like the offerName in the JSON by using the following syntax in a variable and calling it in the console:

```
var OfferName = data.offersBreakdown.allOffers[0].offers[0].offerName;
```

However this only pulls in the first iteration of offerName because in the variable I've set it to look into the first iteration of its parent, 'offers'. What I'm looking to do is create a variable which prints all of the offerName data so that I can call on it instead of the data_test variable further down in the code, which processes the data into HTML. Sounds confusing? It is.

Ideally what I think I need is to be able to ask it to look into each child item of 'offers' (rather than just the first one) and then have it look for 'offerName'. I can't work out how one would achieve this. The best I can come up with is to remove the [0] from 'offers', but if I do that, it returns undefined as the result.

Here's my JavaScript (and a bit of jQuery):

```
<script>
// fetch call for the JSON data (see below)
fetch('api_url', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'auth_token'
  }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(function (data) {
    var AllOffers = data.offersBreakdown.allOffers[0];
    var AllOffers_Offers = data.offersBreakdown.allOffers[0].offers;
  
    var OfferName = data.offersBreakdown.allOffers[0].offers[0].offerName;
    var OfferImageUrl = data.offersBreakdown.allOffers[0].offers[0].imageUrl;    
  
    console.log(AllOffers);
  

function createCard(cardData) {
  var cardTemplate = [
    '<div class="card">',
    '<p>My name is: ',
    cardData.Offer || 'No offer',
    '</p>',
    '<p>My job is: ',
    cardData.Img || 'No image',
    '</p></div>'
  ];

  // a jQuery node
  return jQuery(cardTemplate.join(''));
}

var data_test = [
    { "Name": OfferName, "Img": OfferImageUrl },
    { "Name": OfferName, "Img": OfferImageUrl },
    { "Name": OfferName, "Img": OfferImageUrl },
];

var cards = jQuery();
// Store all the card nodes
data_test.forEach(function(item, i) {
  cards = cards.add(createCard(item));
});

// Add them to the page... for instance the <body>
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('body').append(cards);
});
  

</script>
```

Here's the JSON

```
<script>
// the JSON
{
"offersBreakdown": {
"totalAddedOffers": 0,
"totalOffers": 2,
"totalAddedRewards": 0,
"totalRewards": 0,
"totalAddedStreakOffers": 0,
"totalStreakOffers": 0,
"allOffers": [
{
"offers": [
{
"offerName": "Offer name 1",
"imageUrl": "https://url_path_1.jpg"
},
{
"offerName": "Offer name 2",
"imageUrl": "https://url_path_2.jpg"
},
{
"offerName": "Offer name 3",
"imageUrl": "https://url_path_3.jpg"
},
{
"offerName": "Offer name 4",
"imageUrl": "https://url_path_4.jpg"
}
]
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you want help, you're going to need to fix you grammar. A lot of it isn't making sense. Read your question aloud or to someone else and determine what makes sense and fix whatever doesn't make sense.

Comment: JSON is a text format, and after the call to `response.json()` it's been parsed to an object (not a JSON object, just a plain old JavaScript object). See http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: So, the answer to this question is "loop through the arrays as needed to get the information you need". You seem to understand how to do this (you use `forEach` elsewhere in the code), so what are you looking for from us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming what you're looking for is a way to loop through all of the `offerName`s, in which case a simple `for` loop would suffice. Since your data includes nested arrays and objects, we need two loops, one to iterate through your `allOffers` array and then a nested `for` loops to iterate through the `offers` array inside of your `allOffers` array

```
        var data = {
            "offersBreakdown": {
                "totalAddedOffers": 0,
                "totalOffers": 2,
                "totalAddedRewards": 0,
                "totalRewards": 0,
                "totalAddedStreakOffers": 0,
                "totalStreakOffers": 0,
                "allOffers": [{
                    "offers": [{
                        "offerName": "Offer name 1",
                        "imageUrl": "https://url_path_1.jpg"
                    }, {
                        "offerName": "Offer name 2",
                        "imageUrl": "https://url_path_2.jpg"
                    }, {
                        "offerName": "Offer name 3",
                        "imageUrl": "https://url_path_3.jpg"
                    }, {
                        "offerName": "Offer name 4",
                        "imageUrl": "https://url_path_4.jpg"
                    }]
                }]
            }
        };
        var allOffers = [];
        var jsonObjectAllOffers = data.offersBreakdown.allOffers;
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObjectAllOffers.length; i++) {
            var offers = jsonObjectAllOffers[i].offers;
            for (var j = 0; j < offers.length; j++) {
                var objectToAppend = {
                    "Name": offers[j]["offerName"],
                    "Img": offers[j]["imageUrl"]
                };
                allOffers.push(objectToAppend);
            }
        }
        console.log(allOffers);
```

And now you can use your `allOffers` variable to loop through with the "forEach" and make into HTML

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I'm a little brain-frazzled from working on this for the last two days without much progress, but I can't figure out how/where to use the piece which you just constructed. I replaced ```jsonObject``` with ```offersBreakdown``` but can't figure out what to replace ```objectToAppend``` with.

Comment: The you're good, you don't replace it with anything, what the code does is it creates a temporary object so that you can append it to your list of offers.

Comment: Hmm....I tried that but I get a console error saying "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: jsonObject is not defined" which made me wonder if it needed to be changed.

Comment: You changed the `jsonObject` correctly but I was saying you don't need to change the `objectToAppend`

Comment: I've tried that also, but now getting "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" from the console. Can I please hire you for 30 minutes to get this working please? I don't know how to send a Private Message on here.

Comment: I don't see how you can hire me  but I'd be happy to help

Comment: What does `data.offersBreakdown.allOffers`show in your console?

Comment: I'd like to hire you to work your magic and get this script working...if you have a website or portfolio to reach you on, please let me know.

I tried data.offersBreakdown.allOffers but it doesn't return anything. However if I add it inside a console.log statement, it returns everything inside the object, ie:
[{…}]
0:
addedOffers: 0
groupTitle: ""
offers: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
totalOffers: 5
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: So `var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data).offersBreakdown.allOffers` should work with the script I provided, sorry i don't have a resume or a portfolio, however we can private chat on stack overflow if you'd like

Comment: Ok please check my answer now, it is working fine on my end

Comment: Thank you once again - I feel like it's close....but it's still not quite there yet. When I paste the code into the console it returns the values, but it needs me to click on the little arrow thing to enter one level into the code. I feel like it needs to go one level deeper, if that makes sense? For what it's worth, if I run an alert(allOffers); it will return [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Feel free to give me a shout via stackoverflow at semanta.co.uk :)

My post count is too low, so it won't let me message you in a chat window.

Comment: That means the code is working! The console arrow thing is just for simplicity and what you were looking for in the first place was an array of objects that you can iterate over

Comment: I'm so confused...,is it possible to have it display all of the required values in an alert prompt or showing in console log without clicking on the arrow to expand the data set? Please drop me an email if that's easier for you.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: If you plug in this code into what you already have, it should work with your calls to HTML

Comment: I owe you one man....can't thank you enough for your help, really. Please let me know your PayPal so I can send you some money? Please give me a shout on stackoverflow@semanta.co.uk to share details with me there.

Comment: Once again, thank you so much for your help. It might have been something simple for you, but for me, it saved my job and I'm so grateful. Please ping me on stackoverflow@semanta.co.uk when you have a moment sir :)